# Maximize $x^2 + y^2$ subject to $1 \leq 2 x^2 + 4 y^2 \leq 4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, non-convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker, qcqp

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & x^2 + y^2\\ \text{subject to} & 1 \leq 2 x^2 + 4 y^2 \leq 4\end{array}$$

I don't know how to apply the KKT conditions here, maybe there is other method but I´m not sure how to apply it. Thanks for the help you can give me.

Comment: IMO the problem is totally linear, assuming that $x, y$ are real numbers.

Comment: Have you made a [drawing](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%E2%89%A42x%C2%B2%2B4y%C2%B2%E2%89%A44) ? You're willing to maximize $\|(x,y)\|^2$ on the set $1\leqslant 2x^2+4y^2\leqslant4$, which is the difference between two (filled) ellipses. Basic geometry involved, nothing fancy : maximize $\|(x,y)\|^2$ on the boundary of the biggest ellipse.

Comment: How about maximizing $u+v$ subject to the constraints $u\ge0,v\ge0,1\le2u+4v\le1$, instead?

Comment: To find the maximum, you can also note that $$x^2+y^2\leq \frac{2x^2+4y^2}{2}\leq \frac{4}{2}=2\,.$$  The equality holds if and only if $2x^2+4y^2=4$ and $y^2=0$.$$ \phantom{a}$$  You can also find the minimum by observing that $$x^2+y^2\geq \frac{2x^2+4y^2}{4}\geq \frac{1}{4}\,.$$ The equality occurs if and only if $2x^2+4y^2=1$ and $x^2=0$.